# What is the correct choice for the sentence below?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

The sentence is

> "I'd like a cake and a cup of tea, please."
> Waiter: "............"
>
> A. Here it is.
> B. Here they are.

what is the correct answer to put in the space for the waiter? Should it be singular or plural?

Comment: It's not that definite. Here it [your order] is, here they [the items you ordered] are. I would post B though for the test question.

Comment: More colloquial than either are: "Here you are," or even "There you go."

Comment: It might help f you told us what you think and why.